# how to set value for input type file and store in data base in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I am trying for generating insert query but input type file value is not displaying. 
I just want to set value default in photo.
pls
here is code

```
<?php $photo = "photo.jpg";?>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $photo = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
        $photo_tmp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
        echo "INSERT INTO items(photo)VALUES($photo)";
    }
    ?>

    <form method="post">
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
        var photo = document.getElementById('photo').value;
        photo = "<?php echo $photo; ?>";
        //alert(photo);
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag

Comment: There are many issues here. `$photo` is just a string, your input is looking for a file. Your `<form` won't submit a file. Your SQL is open to injections and invalid. I don't see the reason for the JS. Additionally your SQL is just a string, not being executed, nor using `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your php. You dont have to do it with jquery.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_dir = "../profilepics/";    
$target_final = $target_dir."photo".'.'.end($temp);
```

and continue to add it as `$target_final` to db.